# What is the latest version for SharePoint Designer 2013 64-bit inside windows 10

Tags: sharepoint-designer, administration, upgrade, installation, windows10

I use to have windows 7 which contain sharepoint designer 32-bit, and its version was `15.0.4849.100`, as follow:-
[image]

but inside my windows 10 PC, i installed the sharepoint designer 64-bit from this link @ https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491, and after that i checked the version for the SP designer, which was lower than the previous version. the new version is `15.0.4420.1017`, as follow:-
[image]

So i am not sure how i can upgrade my SP designer version inside windows 10? the issue is that inside the above download link they mentioned the following:-

***Please make sure your installation of SharePoint Designer is up to date by using Microsoft Update, or installing Service Pack 1 from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42015)***

but inside the Service Pack 1 download link the supported operating systems do not include windows 10. So i am not sure how i can get the latest version for the SP designer inside windows 10?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone couldn't find yet, latest one is of August 2016 which is a patch over SP1.
URL: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53389

Doesn't come on an easy search for some reason. Anyway, have a great day!

Regards